# tcl 8.3 + Img 1.2.4 - can not load Img

Tags: tcl

sorry I am noob in TCL.

The Img Library is here:

```
/tcl_tk/libtk_8.3.2/libimg1.2.so
/tcl_tk/libtk_8.3.2/libimg1.2.4.so
```

The colleague build the script left the company years ago.
So can not ask him :-(

At the system (AIX) is tcl from IBM Packet installed.
And the older Version here /tcl_tk

When check path with:

```
puts $tcl_pkgPath
puts $auto_path
```

Got this:

```
/opt/freeware/lib
/opt/freeware/lib/tcl8.4 /opt/freeware/lib /usr/lib
```

How can I change the PATH (tcl_pkgPath) to:

```
/tcl_tk/libtk_8.3.2 and /tcl_tk/libtcl_8.3.2
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you perceive: Does executing `package require Img` fail? Is there a file `pkgIndex.tcl` in `tcl_tk/libtk_8.3.2` or `tcl_tk`. If yes, what is its content?

Comment: Can you upgrade to a newer Tcl (8.6) and Img?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're creating a new package, just pretend that `tcl_pkgPath` doesn't exist.

`auto_path` is a list.   To append additional paths, use the `lappend` command:

```
lappend auto_path path1 path2 path3
```

To completely redefine `auto_path`, then use `set`:

```
set auto_path [list path1 path2 path3]
```

I see that the library you want end with .so, so it's a C-extension. I believe you need to use `load` instead of `package require` for this.

See more about `load`:  https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/load